# Distributional Derivative of delta function.

Tags: distribution-theory, weak-derivatives

I am given with Heaviside function
$$
H(x) :=  \begin{cases}
0, & \text{if } x \in (-\infty, 0) \\ 
1, & \text{if } x \in (0,\infty).
\end{cases}
$$
I have calculated its distributional derivative $$T_{H'}(x) = -\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} H(x) \phi'(x) dx$$ where $\phi$ is a test function and $T_{H'}$ represents distributional derivative. 
After calculating it I get $$T_{H'} = \delta,$$ where $\delta (\phi(x)) = \phi(0)$ is the delta function. How can I find out the distributional  derivative of the delta function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition:

$$\delta'(\phi) = -\delta (\phi') = - \phi'(0)$$